# Syntax highlighting does not work for shell scripts written in bash

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I tried using the `<!-- language: bash -->` and also an option from this question - [bash doesn't format properly without language comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260467/5291015), but neither of `lang-bsh` or `lang-sh` work too.

A snippet of the problem caused is something like below, note the part after `##` is treated as if it were a comment.

[image]

Comment: This looks like an issue with Google Prettify. That's how the library formats this code.

Comment: I think this is similar to this [bug report](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/355) on the Google Prettify GitHub repository. If you're able to improve their current regex for the Bash parser, I suggest you offer them a PR. Then it still needs time (6 to 8 weeks) before SE will update to a new stable release of that library.